# probability and simulation for baseball games

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In order for a baseball team to win the world series,the team must win four of seven games. assume the two teams are equally likely to win. 1) Using a simulation with 25 trials,what is the probaility that the teams in the world series will play all seven games? 2) Often we do the same simulation to answer different question.Using the same simulation data,what is the average number of games that must be played to win the world series? 3) the following data represent the number of games played in each world series from 1923 to 2010. compute the average number of games played and compare that number to your result for question 2 from your simulation.

X(games played)| probability

4|0.1954

5| 0.2069

6 | 0.2184

7 | 0.3793

Note: include an explanation of the simulation process in context for each question and include the data for each trial.

Comment: It appears you are to make a practical *simulation*, not investigate the problem theoretically. We can hardly make the simulation for you.

Comment: Not to mention that it's better to phrase your question in the form of an actual question, rather than instructions for us.

Comment: I posted the link in the answer, but this seems to be a rewording of Jay Hill's World Series problem, from the MSTE online resources page.

Comment: We could show what a simulation would show in theory.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking [here](http://mste.illinois.edu/hill/ev/seriesprob.html), it is a nice lesson that will answer your questions and give you the answers.  Its a lesson by Jay Hill.

It will show you how to solve the problem by both simulation and also analytically.

Answer (score 0):

The first two require a simulation of some sort.  You could just flip a coin manually, or you could program a computer.  For the third, the average number of games played is $\sum_n n \cdot p(n)$.  You have the data for that in your table.